# Recording the user session on JBoss and returning different views based on the session

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, jboss, javabeans

I have a JSF function which returns different views depending on certain information stored on the user currently viewing/manipulating the page. I.e. depending if the customer has a gold/silver/bronze subscription, the view will display different amounts of information. Is there a JBoss way to do this simply? I read something about SessionBean but I am not sure as to how to implement it, or even if the Bean will contain the data that I need.

BTW I am on JBoss 7.1 with JPA 2 and Java EE 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
```

gets the name of the person currently logged in!

Answer (score 0):

WHat about this solution.

-you can create 3 separate beans for each subscription type and have all the rendering logic in their eg:

SilverBean
GoldBean
BronzeBean

and then have a central bean called: SomeBean. Now what you can do is inject the three beans in the SomeBean.

You can then have a Map and then store the beans linking to the subscribtion type.

When the user loggs in you can then search for their subscription type and then render the view with the requried bean.